# Cambiar un option del select gracias a otra option

Tags: javascript, html

Lo que intento es algo bastante básico, pero no lo consigo porque los ejemplos que veo no son nada similares a lo que ando buscando.

Hay 2 `select`, uno de ellos lo escoges tu manualmente y el otro dinámicamente cambia dependiendo del `value` del primero.

Si el `value` del primer `select` es 1, que en el segundo solo aparezcan cuyo `value` sea 1 también.

**Lo quiero hacer 100% JavaScript, no quiero nada de JQuery.**

##### `HTML.php`

```html
<select onchange="coger_value_tipos()" name="tipos" id="tipos">
    <option value="1">Carnes</option>
    <option value="2">Pescados</option>
    <option value="3">Verduras</option>
</select>

<select name="comida" id="comida">
    <option value="1">Cerdo</option>
    <option value="1">Vaca</option>
    <option value="1">Pollo</option>
    <option value="2">Sardina</option>
    <option value="2">Salmón</option>
    <option value="2">Caballa</option>
    <option value="3">Espinacas</option>
    <option value="3">Kale</option>
    <option value="3">Guisantes</option>
</select>
```

##### `JavaScript.js`

```js
function coger_value_tipos() {
     var tipos_value_option = document.getElementById("tipos").value;

     // ¿Qué más añado aquí?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías replantear todo lo que tienes hecho. Yo te hago un ejemplo de como podrías hacer funcionar lo que buscas:

En el HTML solo deja el select de con id tipos.

A partir de ahí el Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
const typeSelect = document.getElementById('tipos');

    const foods = [
        {type: 1, food: 'Cerdo'},
        {type: 1, food: 'Vaca'},
        {type: 1, food: 'Pollo'},
        {type: 2, food: 'Sardina'},
        {type: 2, food: 'Salmón'},
        {type: 2, food: 'Caballa'},
        {type: 3, food: 'Espinacas'},
        {type: 3, food: 'Kale'},
        {type: 3, food: 'Guisantes'}
    ]

    function createFoodSelect(){
        let newSelect = document.createElement('select');
        newSelect.id = 'comida';
        typeSelect.after(newSelect);
    }

    typeSelect.addEventListener('change', function(){
        let selectedId = this.value;
        let foodsSelected = foods.filter(f => f.type === Number(selectedId));
        if(!document.getElementById('comida')){
            createFoodSelect();
        }
        let foodSelect = document.getElementById('comida');
        if(foodSelect.length){
            for(let i = foodSelect.length; i >= 0; i--){
                foodSelect.remove(i);
            }
        }
        if(foodsSelected.length){
            foodsSelected.forEach((f, i) => {
                foodSelect.add(new Option(f.food, i));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Como consejo, deberías manejar la fuente de los datos del select 'comida' de forma dinámica. Esto es un ejemplo rápido para que te hagas una idea.